# The compatibility issue between NDIS version and Windows version

Tags: c++, driver, compatibility, winpcap, ndis

everyone. I am doing some modifications to the WinPcap, a packet capturing library. My boss want me to transfer the NDIS version of WinPcap from NDIS 4 to NDIS 6. And the compatibility requirement is Windows XP/Vista/7/8 (32bit and 64bit). I found that the latest version of NDIS is 6.3, but I'm afraid that NDIS 6.3 does not support XP any more, is this true? Also I found in WinPcap website that the current WinPcap 4.1.3 has already supported Windows XP/2003/Vista/2008/Win7/2008R2/Win8 (x86 and x64). Is it right? Which version of NDIS should I update to keep the widest compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm afraid that NDIS 6.3 does not support XP any more, is this true?

If you mean "will a driver that uses NDIS 6.3 work on Windows XP", the answer is "no", and has always been "no"; it's not a case of "any more".

A given version of Windows supports a given version of NDIS (not the other way around).  "NT 5.x", i.e. Windows 2000, Windows XP, and their server equivalents, support NDIS 5; an NDIS 6 driver (even NDIS 6.0) won't work on those versions of Windows.  An NDIS 6 driver requires "NT 6.x", i.e. Windows Vista and later.

If you look at [Microsoft's MSDN documentation on network drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll notice that it has a section for "Network Drivers Starting with Windows Vista" and a section for "Network Drivers Prior to Windows Vista"; the first section is for NDIS 6 and the second section is for NDIS 5.  (NDIS 4 is, I guess, considered too old to bother documenting any more; I don't know what the differences between NDIS 4 and NDIS 5 were, or whether WinPcap still supports NDIS 4.)

Your options, if you want to support NDIS 6 in WinPcap (for example, to support monitor mode on Wi-Fi devices) are:

- make a version of WinPcap that doesn't support Windows 2000 or Windows XP or their server versions, and that only supports NDIS 6;
- make separate versions of the WinPcap driver and packet.dll library for "NT 5" (W2K/WXP and their server versions) and "NT 6" (Vista, 7, 8 and their server versions), give the two versions of packet.dll the same API (with the "NT 5" version, for example, returning a failure indication for attempts to put the interface into monitor mode), and have wpcap.dll (i.e, the "libpcap" part of WinPcap) using that API, and have the installer figure out which one to install (which means you'd have to reinstall WinPcap to get the NDIS 6 features if you upgrade an "NT 5" system to "NT 6", e.g. upgrading Windows XP to Windows Vista, 7, or 8) or somehow have the right driver code run when the driver is loaded, if that's possible.

Note, by the way, that, if your goal is to support monitor mode on NDIS devices, you are ***VERY STRONGLY*** advised to implement the APIs that already exist in libpcap for monitor mode, i.e. the `pcap_create()`/`pcap_activate()` APIs for opening a device, the `pcap_set_rfmon()` API for requesting monitor mode, and the `pcap_can_set_rfmon()` API for checking whether monitor mode can be turned on, as those APIs are what programs such as tcpdump and Wireshark expect.

Note also that the `pcap_create()`/`pcap_activate()` APIs do not currently handle remote packet capture, so you'll either have to get rid of that capability or wait for me (or somebody) to add those capabilities to those APIs.

Note also that it has been reported that, whilst NDIS 6 has APIs to support monitor mode, not all Wi-Fi devices have NDIS 6 drivers, not all those that do have NDIS 6 drivers have NDIS 6 drivers that support Native Wi-Fi (and thus do not have NDIS 6 drivers that support monitor mode), and even those that *do* have NDIS 6 drivers that support Native 802.11 don't necessarily have NDIS 6 drivers free of bugs that make the Native 802.11 stuff work well.

And, in addition, note also that the "radio information" header supplied by Native 802.11 drivers in monitor mode is different from all of the existing "radio information" headers supported by pcap and pcap-ng, and you'll need to request a new `LINKTYPE_`/`DLT_` value for that "radio information" header from tcpdump-workers@lists.tcpdump.org.  Wireshark already has a dissector for it, as it can read 802.11 captures from Microsoft Network Monitor; tcpdump will need one.

(If you're doing this for some other reason, such as adding support for PPP devices or fixing the code to get the vendor's device description, that might also require making the NDIS 6 driver a lightweight filter driver or something such as that rather than a transport driver.)

Comment: The "parallel drivers" scheme was used to support Windows 95/98/Me and NT back when 95/98/Me were supported, so there's precedent for such a scheme.

Comment: Is there a single NDIS version supports all platforms from XP to 8? I know the NDIS released with WDK7.1.0 supports XP and Win7 at the same time. I don't know its NDIS version, maybe 5.1? Does Win8 support NDIS 5.1 drivers? Here is the link from MS for WDK7.1.0: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Guy said...  XP cannot and has never supported NDIS 6, so your requirement of creating an NDIS 6 driver with XP compatibility is an impossible requirement.  You must change the requirement; either of Guy's options are good (drop XP support, or maintain parallel 5.1 and 6.0 drivers).

Architecturally, packet capturing should be done in an NDIS 6 LWF (and not using a protocol driver with loopback packets).  I suggest starting with a clean, empty LWF (see the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/NDISLWFSYS-Sample-NDIS-60-42b76875)) and adding on the packet capturing functionality from WinPcap.

Comment: Is there a single NDIS version supports all platforms from XP to 8? I know the NDIS released with WDK7.1.0 supports XP and Win7 at the same time. I don't know its NDIS version, maybe 5.1? Does Win8 support NDIS 5.1 drivers? Here is the link from MS for WDK7.1.0: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800

Comment: Yes. It's called "NDIS 5".  WinPcap has an NDIS 5 driver, and supports W2K through 8.  There is, however, no single NDIS version that 1) supports all platforms from XP to 8 and 2) makes happy a boss who wants you to use NDIS 6.  There is also, for example, no NDIS version that 1) supports all platforms from XP to 8 and 2) supports Native 802.11 and thus lets you capture in monitor mode.

Comment: Hello @JeffreyTippet I installed winpcap 4.1 on xp which includes ndis 5, but i cant find 32 bit mingw32 that has headers to build driver with. (I need mingw) also after winpcap installation, gcc driver_ndis.c -lwinpcap be enough for compile?